# Azure Storage Account access from a .Net Framework 4.6.1 app

Tags: .net, azure

I have a legacy Winforms app I'm adding a feature to upload files to an Azure storage account. The app is using .Net 4.6.1 and it seems the only Nuget package available is Azure.Blob.Storage for .Net6.0. I've tried including this but it leads to other issues with missing DLL's. Is this the correct package to use?

```
                    Public Function StreamFileFromAzureStorageAcct(ByVal clientLocalFilePath As String, ByVal containerDestName As String, ByRef strReturn As String) As StreamReader

    'Dim strReturn As String = String.Empty
    Dim textInStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim textIn As StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim connectionString As String = Nothing

    Try

        connectionString = String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1};EndpointSuffix={2}", modConfigSettings.AzureStorageAcctName, modConfigSettings.AzureStorageAcctKey, modConfigSettings.AzureStorageAcctURL)
        Dim Container As BlobContainerClient = New BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerDestName)

        Dim BlobClient As BlobClient = Container.GetBlobClient(Path.GetFileName(clientLocalFilePath))

        Dim readOptions As BlobOpenReadOptions = New BlobOpenReadOptions(False)
        readOptions.Position = 0

        ''Azure Storage Acct Read call returns a Stream
        textInStream = BlobClient.OpenRead(readOptions)

        '' Pass the Stream to a StreamReader to stay inline with existing code.
        textIn = New StreamReader(textInStream)

        strReturn = "Success"

        Return textIn

    Catch er As Exception
        strReturn = String.Format("Failed to Stream from Storage Account: {0}-File:{1}-connectionString: {2}-{3}", er.Message, Path.GetFileName(clientLocalFilePath), connectionString, er.StackTrace)
    End Try

    Return Nothing

End Function

Failed to Stream from Storage Account: The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception.-
```

at System.SpanHelpers.IsReferenceOrContainsReferencesT
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.get_ResponseClassifier200()
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.CreateGetPropertiesRequest(String snapshot, String versionId, Nullable`1 timeout, String leaseId, String encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, String encryptionAlgorithm, String ifTags, RequestConditions requestConditions, RequestContext context) at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.GetProperties(String snapshot, String versionId, Nullable`1 timeout, String leaseId, String encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, String encryptionAlgorithm, String ifTags, RequestConditions requestConditions, RequestContext context)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.d__124.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.d__98.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.OpenRead(BlobOpenReadOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at DBAccessObjects.RemFredDataAdmin.StreamFileFromAzureStorageAcct(String clientLocalFilePath, String containerDestName, String& strReturn) in C:\Users\csale\source\Workspaces\Application Server\FredServer\DBAccessObjects\RemFredDataAdmin.vb:line 15904

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: 4.6.1 reached End Of Life. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2. .NET 6 is actually .NET Core 6, not .NET Framework. You can't use packages that target .NET 6 in .NET Framework at all. You can only use packages that target .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Framework

Comment: [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/#supportedframeworks-body-tab) targets .NET Standard 2.0. You can use it directly. If you target 4.6.2 you won't have any problems. In the discontinued 4.6.1 there were quite a few problems with compatibility packages to the point that there just was no reason to even try.

Comment: Finally all supported Windows versions come with 4.7.2 if not 4.8. Do you really need to target 4.6?

Comment: thank you for your response.  I am aware the diff between the two, that's why i was puzzled when Nuget suggested the Core assemblies. I'll upgrade to 4.6.2 and use the .Net Standard 2.0 option.

Comment: NuGet doesn't suggest .NET 6. There's a single package that targets .NET Standard 2.0 which covers all supported .NET Framework versions. .NET Standard 2.1 which is only for .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 (discontinued) and .NET 6, which also covers .NET 7 and 8

Answer (score 1):

@Panagiotis Kanavos thank you for your comments

As Per @Panagiotis Kanavos Comments, I tried the below code in  **.NET 4.6.2**  using NuGet package  **Azure.Storage.Blobs**  version - **12.8.0** and I can upload files to Azure Blob Storage.

**Code**  :

```c
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class BlobController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadBlob()
    {
        string connectionString = "<Conne_String>";
        string containerName = "<container_name>";
        string blobName = "<blob_name>";
        string filePath = "<filepath>";

        try
        {
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(fs, true);
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "Blob uploaded successfully!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Output**  :

The blob uploaded successfully as below:

[image]

**Azure Storage**  :

[image]

Then, I published the above code to the Azure app service as a web app:

[image]

After Deployment, I uploaded the file successfully.

**Deployment Output**  :

[image]

Comment: I confirm it worked for me as well. I tried my code to stream the blob back down to client and getting a "Failed to Stream from Storage Account: The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception."  error on the "OpenRead()" call. I posted complete code and stacktrace above.